# How to set 20% alpha value for Android Imagebutton?

Tags: android, view

I have a problem in using alpha value. I know how to set alpha value for background but I don't know how to set 20% alpha value for ImageButton.

```
imageButton.setAlpha(?)
```

Can anyone give me full details tutorial on this topic by which I can understand this topic better?

Comment: test `imageButton.setAlpha(0.2)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a tutorial for this, just read the javadoc of the method, which says:

> setAlpha() - Sets the opacity of the view. This is a value from 0 to
>   1, where 0 means the view is completely transparent and 1 means the
>   view is completely opaque.

20% transparent then would mean a value of 0.2.